# Check whether the following function have real solutions or not? $\log_{1.5}(\text{arccot x}-\text{sgn}(e^x))=2$

Tags: calculus, functions

Check whether the following function have real solutions or not?
$\log_{1.5}(\text{arccot x}-\text{sgn}(e^x))=2$

---

My Attempt:
$\log_{1.5}(\text{arccot x}-\text{sgn}(e^x))=2\Rightarrow \frac{\log(\text{arccot x}-\text{sgn}(e^x))}{\log1.5}=2$
$\text{arccot x}-\text{sgn}(e^x)=2.25$
$\text{arccot x}-1=2.25$
$\text{arccot x}=3.25$

I took $\text{sgn}(e^x)=1$, because exponential function is always positive.
So the real solution is possible in this case.

Am i right here?

Comment: Yes. You are right if $x$ is real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, we have

$$\log_{1.5}(\text{arccot}(x)-\operatorname{sgn}(e^x))=2$$
$$\iff \text{arccot}(x)=3.25\tag1$$

But, then, $(1)$ has **no** real solutions because the range of usual principal value of $y=\text{arccot}(x)$ is $0\lt y\lt \pi$. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values))